# Web based web cam recording and uploading software

Tags: flash, video, video-capture

I'm looking for a software that I can incorporate in my website that can record at a click from the users web cam and upload to the website.

It would naturally be restricted to a certain length but is there software out there that can do this?

Note: I'm not looking for screen capture software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash can send a camera stream to a server to be recorded. You could use [red5](http://www.red5.org/) which is open source to do the server side of it. [Here is an article on video/audio recording](http://www.newviewnetworks.com/nvnhome/blog/client/?p=202)